# JSONStore complex queries

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

How would you implement the following query against JSONStore

In SQL format it is

```
select * from table where (A or B) and (C or D)
```

I'm assuming we would use an `advancedFind` operation with an array of `QueryParts`, however in the samples I can see how you can use `QueryParts` to form and `AND` but not how to form an `OR` query.

Any guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking your example SQL and giving it values it would look like this:

`select * from people where (name = 'carlos' or name = 'mike') AND (rank = 'king' or rank = 'pawn')`

Which is the same as:

`select * from people where (name = 'mike' AND rank = 'king') or (name = 'carlos' AND rank = 'pawn') or (name = 'carlos' AND rank = 'king') or (name = 'mike' and rank = 'pawn')`

That can be expressed by JSONStore pseudocode like this:

```
var queryPart1 = WL.JSONStore.QueryPart()
    .equal('name', 'mike') //and
    .equal('rank', 'king');
//or
var queryPart2 = WL.JSONStore.QueryPart()
    .equal('name', 'carlos') //and
    .equal('rank', 'pawn');
//or
var queryPart3 = WL.JSONStore.QueryPart()
    .equal('name', 'carlos') //and
    .equal('rank', 'king');
//or
var queryPart4 = WL.JSONStore.QueryPart()
    .equal('name', 'mike') //and
    .equal('rank', 'pawn');

WL.JSONStore.get('people').advancedFind([queryPart1, queryPart2, queryPart3, queryPart4])
.then(...);
```

Everything inside a query part must match (i.e. it's like an `and`) and as long as one query part matches (i.e. it's like an `or`) results will be returned. Remember to work with top-level search fields.

Sometimes these fairly complex searches are required, but more often than not I would recommend re-thinking the offline experience. I wrote about that [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/offline_patterns?lang=en).

FYI - Feature requests [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014907906&ps=25). Bug reports [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21507639).